# I'm facing errors in my Laravel learning project where I'm facing npm run dev problem in Laravel Authentication how can i solve this problem?

Tags: laravel, npm

hello i'm beginner at Laravel. i'm trying to learn Laravel Authentication but i'm facing errors.
I'm facing errors in my Laravel learning project where I'm facing  npm run dev problem in Laravel Authentication how can i solve this problem?
here are the steps i've took

**I've installed node.js and set the Authentication by**

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

**after that**

```
npm install --verbose
```

**here Is my CMD Command**

```
    PS C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp> npm run dev
```

**Here is the errors I'm Facing:**

```
> @ dev C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp
> npm run development


> @ development C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp
> mix

[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\Vue.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\ComponentRegistrar.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Mix.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js:6:42)
    at Module._compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin-webpack5.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\Vue.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\ComponentRegistrar.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\Mix.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\setup\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myapp\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-21T05_52_12_933Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-21T05_52_12_972Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please give your question a title that briefly describes your problem, more info : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please execute npm run watch

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9493 seems to be an issue with the vue-loader - can you try to update it?